# trying to get tweets from the full day on a specific date but it wont write out to the CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, twitter, tweepy

Trying to get tweepy to get all the tweets that were published by accounts to write to a CSV file.

Program downloads the tweets but will not write them to the CSV file

how can i get the tweets to be written to the CSV file

```
d1 = datetime.date(2016, 8, 4)

for tweet in alltweets:

    #if (datetime.datetime.now() - tweet.created_at).days < 1:
    #for single_date in daterange(d1, d2):
    while True:
        if (tweet.created_at == d1):
        # transform the tweepy tweets into a 2D array that will populate the csv    
        #outtweets.append([tweet.user.name, tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('UTF-8')])
            outtweets.append(list(itertools.chain([tweet.user.name, tweet.created_at],tweet.text.split(' '))))

        else:
            deadend = True
            return
        if not deadend:
            page += 1
    break

#todaysDate = datetime.datetime.now().date()
# write the csv    
with open('%s_%s.csv' % (screen_name, d1), 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["Username", "Tweeted at", "Text"])
    writer.writerows(outtweets)
pass

print ("CSV written")
```

** EDIT 1 **

```
todaysDate = date(2016,8,4)
```

class listener(tweepy.StreamListener):

```
def on_data(self,data):
    print (data)



    with open('%s_.csv' % (todaysDate), 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["Username", "Tweeted at", "Text"])
        writer.writerows(data)
    pass

    print("CSV Written")

    #with open('tweets_file.txt','a') as tf:
        #tf.write(data)
        #tf.close()

    return True

def on_error(self, status):
    print (status)

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_token, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
twitterStream=tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, listener())
while (todaysDate == date(2016, 8, 4)):
    twitterStream.filter()
    todaysDate = date.now()

print("CSV Written")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following (in this example, to get tweets with the word 'Barry'):

```
from tweepy.streaming import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import StreamListener

ckey='yourCkey'
csecret='yourCsecret'
atoken='yourAtoken'
asecret='yourAsecret'

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self,data):
        print data

        with open('tweets_file.txt','a') as tf:
            tf.write(data)
            tf.close()

        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

auth=OAuthHandler(ckey,csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream=Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=['Barry'])
```

Comment: hi, i tried changing the code around and i just keep getting an output of 406, can you tell me if this is on the right track? i put the new code in the EDIT part